# Why is my mongoose populate not retrieving the nested array?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following mongoose schemas:

```
const CategoriesSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
sites: [
  {
    site: {
    type: ObjectId,
    ref: "Sites",
    }
  }
],
);

mongoose.model("Categories", CategoriesSchema, 'organizer-categories');
```

And:

```
const SitesSchema = new Schema({
url: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  img: {
    type: String,
  },

});
mongoose.model("Sites", SitesSchema, "organizer-sites");,
```

The following function is supposed to create a new site in mongodb, add the site to Categories as shown in the schema and return the updated category with the new site data using mongoose's populate method. But only the _id of site is being returned with the category data.

```
exports.addSite = async (req, res) => {
const {categoryId, siteUrl} = req.body;
console.log('categoryId, siteUrl', categoryId, siteUrl)

try {

    let  site = await Sites.findOne({url: siteUrl});

    console.log('site', site)

    if(site) {
        return res.status(422).send(`${siteUrl} already exists.`)
    }

     site = await Sites.create({url: siteUrl, categoryId});
    //  site = {url: siteUrl, categoryId};

     const category = await Categories.findOneAndUpdate({
        _id: categoryId
    }, {
        $addToSet: {
            sites: site
        }
    }, {
        new: true
    }).populate({
        path: 'sites.site',
        model: 'Sites'
    })

 
   console.log('category', category)
    res.status(201).json(category);
} catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
    return res.status(500).send('Error adding category.')    
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

*"mongoose": "^7.2.1"*

The `sites` field within the schema has incorrect arrays of refs. If a category document references an array of site documents, do it like this:

```js
const CategoriesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sites: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Sites" }],
});
```

See [Populate](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#setting-populated-fields)

A working example:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import util from 'util';
import { config } from '../../config';

mongoose.set('debug', true);

const CategoriesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  sites: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Sites" }],
});

const Categories = mongoose.model("Categories", CategoriesSchema, 'organizer-categories');
const SitesSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  url: String
});
const Sites = mongoose.model("Sites", SitesSchema, "organizer-sites");

(async function main() {
  try {
    await mongoose.connect(config.MONGODB_URI);
    // seed
    const categoryDoc = await Categories.create({})
    const site = await Sites.create({ url: 'http://google.com' })

    const category = await Categories.findOneAndUpdate(
      { _id: categoryDoc._id },
      { $addToSet: { sites: site } },
      { new: true })
      .populate('sites')

    console.log('category: ', util.inspect(category, false, null))

  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  } finally {
    await Promise.all(['organizer-categories', 'organizer-sites'].map(c => mongoose.connection.dropCollection(c)))
    await mongoose.connection.close()
  }
})();
```

Logs:

```bash
category:  {
  _id: new ObjectId("64789a6b3ffd33b38a6eaf9a"),
  sites: [
    {
      _id: new ObjectId("64789a6b3ffd33b38a6eaf9c"),
      url: 'http://google.com',
      __v: 0
    }
  ],
  __v: 0
}
```